# Rolled back Sendgrid API via Nuget to old version, now getting hundreds of warnings on build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, sendgrid-api-v3

Using Nuget, I rolled back the Sendgrid API from 9.1 to 9.0.

When I build my project, I now get hundreds of warnings such as:

- warning SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace
- The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file.
- Enable XML documentation output
- Closing brace must be followed by blank line

It still builds, but these warnings were not there previously.

I updated back to 9.1 but the warnings still persist.  I'd like to get rid of them, but I'd rather not go through hundreds of files making irrelevant changes.

Does anyone know what happened when I rolled back the package, and what to do now to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, for some reason `StyleCop` Nuget package was installed at some point during the rollback/rollup.  Removed it from project and messages are gone.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.